# How do I prove that SAT in coNP implies NP=coNP?

Tags: np-complete, satisfiability, np, co-np

Is it true that if SAT is in coNP then its also coNP-complete (because it is NP-complete)?

Answer (score 4):

If SAT is in coNP then since coSAT is coNP-complete, SAT can be reduced to coSAT in polytime. The same reduction also reduces coSAT to SAT. Since coSAT is coNP-complete, every problem in coNP can be reduced in polytime to coSAT, and so to SAT. This shows that SAT is coNP-complete.